# How to get the latitude and longitude from a Google Map marker in order to update in a form?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to make a form that auto-updates the coordinates of a marker. 
Here's my part of the script:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: event.latLng,
    map: map,
  });
  var x = document.getElementById("coordinates");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  };
  var lati, longi;
  lati = event.latLng;
  longi = event.latLng;
  $("#lat").val(lati);
  $("#lng").val(longi);
});
```

And here's the form:

```
<div id="coordinates" class="container" style="margin-top: 10px; display: none;">
  <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
    <input class="form-control" id="lat" name="lat" placeholder="Latitude" type="text" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
    <input class="form-control" id="lng" name="lng" placeholder="Longitude" type="text" required>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate them using `.lat()/.lng()`:

```
var myLatLng = event.latLng;

var lati = myLatLng.lat();
var lngi = myLatLng.lng();

$("#lat").val(lati);
$("#lng").val(longi);
_^______________________ //Make sure you correct the typo here
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `.lat()` and `.lng()` methods of the `google.maps.LatLng` object to get the individual fields:

```
var lati, longi;
lati = event.latLng.lat();
longi = event.latLng.lng();
$("#lat").val(lati);
$("#lng").val(longi);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/0pccgswh/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map,
    });
    var x = document.getElementById("coordinates");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    };

    var lati, longi;
    lati = event.latLng.lat();
    longi = event.latLng.lng();
    $("#lat").val(lati);
    $("#lng").val(longi);

  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 95%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="coordinates" class="container" style="margin-top: 10px; display: none;">
  <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
    <input class="form-control" id="lat" name="lat" placeholder="Latitude" type="text" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
    <input class="form-control" id="lng" name="lng" placeholder="Longitude" type="text" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```